# How to make sure the content inside "row" is always the same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to fix a bug in this website, so I reproduce the problem in the sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-engelbart-q70uc8?file=/index.html

So right now the problem is when ever you change the img inside,if the size is different, the layout will extend to different height.

[image]

[image]

You can see as the image change the layout height will change as well, I tried "height" but this will ruin the responsive feature of it, is there any way to mantain the same height but still be able to be responsive?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="py-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center bg-dark text-white min-height">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 d-flex justify-content-end flex-column main-heading">
          <h1 class="display-3 pb-3">Hello</h1>
          <span class="text-info lead">One two three</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 d-md-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/l4Zvchl.jpg" class="img-fluid lazyload" alt="Page Wallpaper" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is standard dynamic (responsive) behavior for Bootstrap. You would have to set a fixed height on either the container or the image itself if you don't want it to change height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add this `style="object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 300px;"` to your `img` element (you can customize it with class), but your image will be cut off a bit due to fixed height as a trade-off.

[Mobile size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh54x.png)

[Desktop size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ggIy.png)

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-fire-bp6vcv?file=/index.html:1095-1141